# How to subquery and FULL Join onto the same table

Tags: join, subquery

I have a SQL Table with alot of Team Names and Queries

For Example:
[image]

I want to do a FULL JOIN to compare the Red Team and Blue Team Only to see who is in Red, in Blue, or in Both. To Get Something Like this.

[image]

If these were two separate tables and didn't have extra groups I could do a FULL JOIN to compare them against each other, but when I've tried a FULL JOIN with the same table, it will throw in mismatches and still compare against the Yellow Team.

Is there a way to subquery to just the groups I want (Red and Blue), then do a FULL join against this subset?

Comment: What database system and version?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: What query do you have so far? Please do not post images of code or data, please paste them in as text. Which DBMS are you using, please tag.